# Using Raspberry Pi as USB device description pass-through/emulator

Tags: usb, usb-hub

**TLDR:** Is it possible to use a Pi (or Pi like device) as a method for emulating a USB device descriptor and passing packets across?
If I could get the Pi to emulate the correct ID and details, I could have the application (fastboot) recognise the device (phone) and therefore pass the content between one-another.

---

**Long version:**

I've got a device (phone) that won't detect on my PC running Windows 10. I've tried multiple Windows devices, Linux devices, different chipsets and CPU brands, multiple cables, the lot. On all cases, the device (phone) comes up as "Unknown USB device (Device Descriptor Request Failed)" in Device manager, and under events lists "Device USB\VID_0000&PID_0002\7&192ea77b&0&4 was configured."
I know that's a generic VID & PID so it won't detect the right drivers...

Luckily, via the USB support files,"android_winusb.inf", the drivers provide the USB Device Descriptors that I'd want to emulate for example:

```
%CompositeAdbInterface%    = USB_Install, USB\VID_0B05&PID_4D05&MI_01
%SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0B05&PID_4DAE
%SingleBootLoaderInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0B05&PID_4DAF
```

Currently, none of these line up to my device, because my PC cannot determine what the device is (error = Unknown USB Device (Device Descriptor Request Failed)) so it allocates a generic VID & PID (USB\VID_0000&PID_0002). Therefore, I need I may manually need to set those USB Device Descriptor values (or find a device that can do that and pass data as if it was the device). If I could get the Pi to emulate the correct ID and details, I could have the application (fastboot) recognise the device (phone) and therefore pass the content between one-another. I've tried 2 phones, so I also believe it's not a device issue.

Simple in theory, but I can't find anything that'll do it... and I sure don't have the knowledge to code it!

Comment: so, the phone is recognised correctly on the Pi, just not on your Windows PC?

Comment: Apologies, I've not been clear; No, the phone hasn't been identifiable via USB. The solution would have to provide the emulated/fake device descriptor on behalf of any device that is plugged in.

Comment: but if the device that is plugged in isn't recognised on the pi, how is the pi going to help?

Comment: Hypothetically if a simple solution did exist, the pi would accept any connection on USB1, and route any traffic/requests via USB2 which would emulate the correct/custom USB device descriptor that a PC would typically expect.

Comment: but if the device is not recognised on a Pi, then how is the Pi going to help? Sure you may (not likely) be able to emulate the phone, but emulating the phone doesn't mean the data on the phone is available, since the pi (according to you) does NOT recognise the phone as a device it can communicate with (according to you)

Comment: My expectation is that, hypothetically, if the Pi is able to ignore/replace the USB device descriptor then it should still be able to transfer packets across and get a response. The USB port on the device doesn't seem damaged given it can detect in certain circumstances (adb) but not in the mode that I require (fastboot). The Pi just needs to provide the option to ignore or replace the device descriptors on the parent and child USB ports, then plug into a computer/laptop for transfer. Alternatively, if there is a Pi OS that could skip the 2nd PC requirement, that'd also be lovely!

Comment: I just imagine a pi (or any computer) would need to successfully communicate with a device to do anything useful with it